# how to modify a existing record in c program?

Tags: c

i writing a program which add records, modify records and delete records, the problem i encountered is that i m unable to modify record

```
void recmodify()
{
FILE *fp;
char emp[50];

printf("Name of record :");
scanf("%s",emp);

fp=fopen("C:\\New folder\\babarecord.dat","rb+");
if(fp==NULL)
{
    printf("errorrrr!11");
}
    rewind(fp);
 while((fread(&a,sizeof(a),1,fp))>0)
    {
     if(a.name==emp)
                {           printf("%s   %s    %f\n\n\n\n",a.name,a.date,a.amount);

                            printf("\nName : ");
                            scanf("%s",a.name);
                            printf("\nDate(DD-MM-YYYY) : ");
                            scanf("%s",a.date);
                            printf("Amount : ");
                            scanf("%f",&a.amount);
                            fseek(fp,-sizeof(a),1);
                            fwrite(&a,sizeof(a),1,fp);
                            getch();
                }
    }
   }
```

when i execute, until i enter the name of record to modify everything works ok bt as soon as i press enter program automatically terminates.

Comment: `if(a.name==emp)` will never be true, because you compare the *locations* of the strings. You must use `strcmp` such as `if(strcmp(a.name, emp) == 0)`

Comment: ... but we need to see the `struct` definition too please. Aside: please use `SEEK_CUR` not a magic number.

Comment: After `if(fp==NULL)` is true you carry on reading the file when it does not exist. In this function, you do not close the file you opened. Are other functions lacking too?

Comment: no actually i missed fclose() in above function only thanks Weather Vane u jst solved my  problem thank u......bt one thing i didnt understand why do it carry on reading the file even though if(fp==NULL) is true

Comment: Because you don't quit. You announce that the file can't be opened with `"errorrrr!11"`, but carry on to read it anyway.

Comment: hmm...again thanks a lot i again missed exit().....again thanks a lot